# jQuery ajax request awkward issue

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

So I have this ajax request. When the user clicks an edit link, I fetch the ID of the entry and refresh the page with the data of that entry loaded into a form.

Here's my problem: This only works with the alert showing before the ajax call. When I leave out the alert, I get an ajax error (though the id is being posted) and the PHP page just reloads. Moreover, it only works when I put the newDoc stuff as a success callback. The exact same lines as a complete callback and the page reloads. Moreover, this occurs in Firefox only.

```
jQuery('a.edit').on('mousedown', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = jQuery(this).attr('data-title');
    alert('test');
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: document.location,
        data: {
            id: id
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var newDoc = document.open("text/html", "replace");
            newDoc.write(data);
            newDoc.close();
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
```

What can I do?

**EDIT: This must be a timing issue.** I just noticed that when I click and hold the edit link for a second or so, everything works fine. When I do a short click, it doesn't. So I tried wrapping the ajax in setTimeout(), but that didn't help. Any other ideas?

Comment: why are you using `jQuery` instead of `$`?

Comment: Why are you making an Ajax call than opening a window, why don't you just open the window to start?

Comment: @bansi using `jQuery` is prefered over `$`. takes away lot of your headaches while writing cross framework/library codes.

Comment: I am developing a Wordpress plugin, hence the jQuery. I don't open a window, I load the new code in the same window and add page history. Before I did that, there was no "refresh" on the page so I couldn't see the results of the values posted to the PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `location.href` in place of `document.location`,

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: location.href,
    data: {
        id: id
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var newDoc = document.open("text/html", "replace");
        newDoc.write(data);
        newDoc.close();
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

`location` is a structured object, with properties corresponding to the parts of the URL. `location.href` is the whole URL in a single string.

Comment: Tried it, same issue. I don't see why document.location should be wrong. I checked the path and it's the right one. Under the circumstances described in my post, it works finde with document.location.

Comment: **document.location** is an `object` and `ajax url` should be an `string` read http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

The problem is the way Firefox handles the *mousedown* event. It seems to abort the ajax call as soon as you relase the mouse button. I changed the event to *click* and everything is fine now.

```
jQuery('a.edit').on('click', function () {
    var id = jQuery(this).attr('data-title');
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: document.location,
        data: {
            id: id
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var newDoc = document.open("text/html", "replace");
            newDoc.write(data);
            newDoc.close();
        }
    });
});
```